# Inserting new row into table before last row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning,

I'm currently trying to insert a row into my table which must fall before the last row.  I've tried a few different methods but I can't seem to get it working.  Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

I have tried toying with `jQuery('table.tablesubmit tr:last').append(newRow);` and adding `.before` but it threw an error (Cannot read property 'append' of undefined).  I'm new to jQuery, so apologies if this is really simple stuff. If there's an easier solution to this, I'm open to suggestions.

I have read over similar threads, but none of which I can get working with my specific example.

I have tried using the following code, and although it adds and removes my rows, it's not behaving as I'd like it to.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var counter = 1;
  jQuery('a.pluslink').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var newRow = jQuery(
      '<tr><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" placeholder="Project"></td>' +
      '<td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +
      '"/></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"/><td>' +
      '<input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +

      '/></td></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +

      '/></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +

      '/></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +

      '"/></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +
      '/></td>' + '<td><a href="#" class="minuslink">Delete</a></td></tr>');
    counter++;
    jQuery('table.tablesubmit').append(newRow);
  });
  $("table.tablesubmit").on('click', '.minuslink', function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="tablesubmit">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="30%">Project name</th>
      <th width="10%">Mon</th>
      <th width="10%">Tue</th>
      <th width="10%">Wed</th>
      <th width="10%">Thur</th>
      <th width="10%">Fri</th>
      <th width="10%">Sat</th>
      <th width="10%">Sun</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="BOSS">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="1.25">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="5">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="5.5">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="" class="minuslink">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bold" width="25%">
        <a>Total Time:</a>
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="7.25" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="8" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="7.5" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="7" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td>37.5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<a href="" class="pluslink">Add new project</a>
```

Comment: _"but it threw an error"_ - And what error?

Comment: _“but it threw an error”_ means you are not only new to jQuery, but apparently also to properly describing a problem to begin with, so please go read [ask].

Comment: Apologies. Cannot read property 'append' of undefined

Comment: Me too @xoog, you just need to select last element and add new row to it using before - `jQuery('table.tablesubmit tr:last').before(newRow);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use this - `jQuery('table.tablesubmit tr:last').before(newRow);`

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var counter = 1;
  jQuery('a.pluslink').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var newRow = jQuery(
      '<tr><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" placeholder="Project"></td>' +
      '<td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +
      '"/></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"/><td>' +
      '<input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +

      '/></td></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +

      '/></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +

      '/></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +

      '"/></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +
      '/></td>' + '<td><a href="#" class="minuslink">Delete</a></td></tr>');
    counter++;
    jQuery('table.tablesubmit tr:last').before(newRow);
  });
  $("table.tablesubmit").on('click', '.minuslink', function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="tablesubmit">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="30%">Project name</th>
      <th width="10%">Mon</th>
      <th width="10%">Tue</th>
      <th width="10%">Wed</th>
      <th width="10%">Thur</th>
      <th width="10%">Fri</th>
      <th width="10%">Sat</th>
      <th width="10%">Sun</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="BOSS">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="1.25">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="5">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="5.5">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="" class="minuslink">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bold" width="25%">
        <a>Total Time:</a>
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="7.25" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="8" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="7.5" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="7" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td>37.5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<a href="" class="pluslink">Add new project</a>
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  More simple than I first thought.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple... Just use before(), here's the link to the jQuery web-page if you want to read more: http://api.jquery.com/before/

```js
    jQuery(function () {
      var counter = 1;
      jQuery('a.pluslink').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var newRow = jQuery(
          '<tr><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" placeholder="Project"></td>' +
          '<td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +
          '"/></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"/><td>' +
          '<input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +
         
          '/></td></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +
          
          '/></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +
         
          '/></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +
         
          '"/></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +
         '/></td>' + '<td><a href="#" class="minuslink">Delete</a></td></tr>');
        counter++;
        jQuery('table.tablesubmit tr:last').before(newRow);
      });
      $("table.tablesubmit").on('click', '.minuslink', function (e) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
      });
    });
```

```html
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <table class="tablesubmit">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th width="30%">Project name</th>
              <th width="10%">Mon</th>
              <th  width="10%">Tue</th>
              <th width="10%">Wed</th>
              <th width="10%">Thur</th>
              <th width="10%">Fri</th>
              <th width="10%">Sat</th>
              <th width="10%">Sun</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="BOSS">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="1.25">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="5">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="1">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="5.5">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0">
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="" class="minuslink">Delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="bold" width="25%">
                  <a>Total Time:</a>
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                  <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="7.25" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                  <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="8" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                  <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="7.5" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                  <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="7" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                  <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                  <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                  <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
                </td> 
                <td>37.5</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <a href="" class="pluslink">Add new project</a>
```

Comment: No problem at all @Xoog, I'm always happy to help when I know the answer off the top of my head!